# AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi.postToConnection() executes twice when called once

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm writing a Lambda function that's called when a message is sent to my WebSocket API, and for now I'm just trying to echo that message back to the sender.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const route = event.requestContext.routeKey;
    const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
        
    switch (route) {
        case '$connect':
            console.log('A client connected:', connectionId);
            break;
        case '$disconnect':
            console.log('A client disconnected:', connectionId);
            break;
        case 'command':
            const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
            const command = body.command;
            console.log('Received a command:', command);
            try {
                await echoCommand(command, connectionId);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Encountered an error when echoing:", err);
            }
            break;
    }
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};

async function echoCommand(command, connectionId) {
    console.log("Inside echo now...");
    const responseData = { command };
    const postParams = {
        ConnectionId: connectionId,
        Data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(responseData))
    };
    
    return api.postToConnection(postParams, (err, data) => {
        if (!err)
            console.log("Successfully echoed the command. Data:", data);
        else
            console.log("Encountered an unknown error:", err);
    }).promise();
}
```

The problem is, even though `echoCommand(...)` is called once, `postToConnection(...)` executes twice.

Logs (after removing unnecessary text):

```
INFO A client connected: d3YK_d77joECEYg=
INFO Received a command: commandToSend
INFO Inside echo now...
INFO Successfully echoed the command. Data: {}
INFO Successfully echoed the command. Data: {}
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's because I used a callback and a promise at the same time.

Remove the callback, like so:

```
async function echoCommand(command, connectionId) {
    console.log("Inside echo now...");
    const responseData = { command };
    const postParams = {
        ConnectionId: connectionId,
        Data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(responseData))
    };
    
    return api.postToConnection(postParams).promise();
}
```

Alternatively, the `.promise()` part can be removed, but I'd rather not; promises are a cleaner and more modern solution than callbacks.

Comment: what is this .promise() on postToConnection return and where it is documented?